# Is the Grails Spring Security plugin still Maintained?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working on an app that requires user registration and permissions. I was looking at the Spring Security Core grails plugin but noticed it is a release candidate that has not been updated since October. Are Spring Security Core and Spring Security UI still supported by Spring or should I consider them no longer actively maintained?

Comment: It is in RC because it is using a milestone version of spring security itself (3.2.0.RC1). This is why a custom repository has to be added to the maven repos in order for it to install correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The lead developer of both plugins is [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith). Although he no longer works for Spring, he still maintains these plugins as you can see from their commit history on GitHub.

Comment: Hmmm... it's 5 months old now... does he still maintain it ?

Comment: what's 5 months old? his last commit was less than 3 months ago https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/commit/a8313d6ce2a7b4c701259890796f32cc51b4f16c